# If you link against a DLL, is it possible to launch your executable if that DLL is missing

Tags: c++, dll

A coworker and I were having a discussion and neither of us is actually sure of how this would work. Let's say that you create a program that uses function Foo() from Bar.DLL.

If Bar.DLL is missing, will it still be possible to launch the program and it will just crash when attempting to call Foo() or will the program simply fail to launch?

Comment: It is technically possible, you have to use the /DELAYLOAD linker option.  It won't crash until you actually call the function.  Using LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress is the boring alternative, but that works as well.

Comment: If by design it is possible for `Bar.DLL` to be missing (maybe it is a optional component), `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` can be used to first test if the DLL is there, and if it is, get a pointer to the exported function `Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to run a app when a dll is missing, is when that dll is DYNAMICALLY LOADED, the app runs and (maybe) shows a error msg, but dont crash

if that dll is statically loaded, the app never runs and OS shows you a standard error msg